# Delay ColorBox Popup For 2 Minutes Site Wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, web, jquery-cookie

I currently have a colorbox popup that pops up immeditaly when you visit the site but I want to delay it so that it doesn popup for 2 minutes but for the whole site and not just the 1 page.

I currently have the following cookie, what code do I need to add to delay it for 2 minutes, if im right all i need to do is get the code and insert it into all pages that way it will keep track of the time the user has been on the site, so what code do I need to add to this:

```
  cb=$.noConflict();
  cb("document").ready(function (){ 

   // load the overlay

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        cb.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
    }

    cb(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});

});
```

Comment: Apologies I accidentally duplicated "var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;" I only have this once in my code just FYI.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove that duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. "setTimeout(function)" added with delay time.

```
cb=$.noConflict();
cb("document").ready(function (){ 
setTimeout(function() {
// load the overlay

if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    cb.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
}
}, 5000); /* 5000 means 5secs delay */

cb(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});

});
```